# Coplanarity of four points

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

Coplanarity of four points.

The points $A(x_1 ,y_1,z_1), B(x_2,y_2,z_2),C(x_3,y_3,z_3),D(x_4,y_4,z_4) $ are coplanar then

**how can we write it like this** .

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you asking why does the determinant satisfy the condition?

Comment: @Rohan yes my doubt is that

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti why does the determinant satisfy the condtion

Comment: The absolute value of the determinant is the volume of the solid defined by AB, AC and AD. So when it is $0$ the solid is flat and the forum points are coplanar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of the tetrahedron formed by four points $P (x_1, y_1, z_1); Q (x_2, y_2, z_2); R (x_3, y_3, z_3); S (x_4, y_4, z_4) $ is given by 
$$6\Delta = \begin {vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1\\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & 1\\
x_4 & y_4 & z_4 & 1\\
\end {vmatrix}$$ $$ =
\begin {vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1\\
x_2-x_1 & y_2-y_1 & z_2-z_1 & 0\\
x_3-x_1 & y_3-y_1 & z_3-z_1 & 0\\
x_4-x_1 & y_4-y_1 & z_4-z_1 & 0\\
\end {vmatrix} $$

If the points are coplanar then the volume of the tetrahedron formed is zero, i.e, $\Delta =0$ the condition automatically follows. Hope it helps.

Comment: That $\Delta$ should be $6\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors $\overrightarrow{AB} , \overrightarrow{AC}, \overrightarrow {AD}$ are coplanar if matrix 
$M= \begin{bmatrix} 
\overrightarrow{AB} & \overrightarrow{AC} & \overrightarrow {AD}  
\end{bmatrix}$   consists of columns linearly dependent i.e $\det(M)=0$.

Of course if $\det(M)=0$ then  also $\det(M^T)=0$.